# Nested loop acting weird

Tags: c++, loops, nested, int

EDIT: Posting everything, because it gets really weird.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int doors = -1;
int jumper = 1;
bool isOpen[100];
string tf;

for(int i = 0 ; i < 100; i++){
    isOpen[i] = false;
}

while(jumper < 100){
    while(doors < 100){
        if(isOpen[doors + jumper] == true){
            isOpen[doors + jumper] = false;
        }
        else{
            isOpen[doors + jumper] = true;
        }
        doors += jumper;
        cout << doors << endl;
    }
    doors = -1;
    jumper+=1;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    if(isOpen[i]){
        tf = "open";
    }
    else{
        tf = "closed.";
    }
    cout << "Door " << i << " is " << tf << endl;
}

return 0;
```

}

So I'm having a very odd problem with this piece of code.
It's supposed to go through an array of 100 items. 0 - 99 by ones then tows then threes, etc. However, after a = 10, it shoots up to 266.
Can anyone tell me why?

Edit: 
This problem only happens when the for loop is commented out. When it is left in the code, it does the same thing, but it doesn't happen until 19.
If I comment out the "string tf;" as well, it continues to loop at 99.
This is all based on the doors count. 
I'm unsure why either of these should be a factor to the loop that neither are connected to.

Comment: Define "shoots". And why are you initializing b to -1?

Comment: What language are you using?  This smells like C, but then again Jay Gosling always did smell a bit like Bjourne Strousup.

Comment: @Amit I mean the next number after 10 is 266. Because I'm going through the array arr[a + b]. So it starts at 0 and goes to 99. I'll post the entire code, because Even weirder things are happening now.

Comment: Playing guess with myself before the upcoming edit: garbaged memory due to buffer overrun

Comment: I just voted down your question because you changed the code, thereby substantially changing all the work which has already been done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description this is what you should do:

```
for(int adv = 1, i = 0; adv < 100;)
{
   // i is array index (your b) -> use it somehow:
   doSomething(arr[i]);

   i += adv;
   if(i >= 100)
   {
       i = 0;
       adv++;
   }
}
```

The (probable) reason you got weird behavior (including the 266 value) is that your code overruns the buffer. When `b` will be high enough (say 99), you'd write to `isOpen[b + a]` which will be 100 or higher (100 if `a` is 1, and that's just the first iteration, later iterations will go much further). If the compiler allocates `isOpen` before the ints you'll be overwriting them.

Comment: Thank you.  I completely see the problem now.